# Runtime Permissions in Android

Tags: android

I'm working on an app which asks for permissions on runtime. How can I make it work on all android versions? Which support runtime permissions and those that don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an a parent activity or a fragment that can handle permissions requests, then create a method that check the permissions so all child's can use it. That method will check the permission and call `onPermissionGranted` or `onPermissionDenied`.

If Android version is lower than M, just instantly call `onPermissionGranted`, otherwise check the permissions normally:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    callback.onPermissionGranted();
    return;
}

//check permissions at runtime...
```

Then run your code that require permissions in `onPermissionGranted` callback in any API level.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running your app on api level 23 or greater you have to ask for permission at runtime, otherwise just add the permission in the Android Manifest as always.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. If your app run on android M you have to ask for permissions, otherwise all permissions are automatically granted (are accepted at install time)

Read the doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I'm using Dexter app permission library! When the app starts it asks for CALL permissions. It works fine on Marshmallow and Nougat but app force closes on lower versions. If I remove the the Dexter permissions the app works fine on lower android versions, but then it doesn't ask for permission on Marshmallow and higher.

Answer (score 0):

In API lever 23 and greater, you will have to manage permission in runtime.

If you design your app targeting on API level 23 or greater, you will not have any problem with older version.

Answer (score 0):

I can share how I handle permissions in an activity.You can put code like below code into your oncreate and onResume. 
         As you see in *if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)*
This code works for Android 6 and above only. 
That is why it starts with *isPermissionOK = true;
*

```
    isPermissionOK = true;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        List<String> requiredPermissions = new ArrayList();
        requiredPermissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
        requiredPermissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);
        requiredPermissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
        requiredPermissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        requiredPermissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK);
        requiredPermissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        requiredPermissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH);
        requiredPermissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN);
        requiredPermissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        requiredPermissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        requiredPermissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        for (int i = 0; i < requiredPermissions.size(); i++) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, requiredPermissions.get(i)) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                isPermissionOK = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    if (!isPermissionOK) {
        return;
    }
```